# pgAdmin4 v7.3 on Windows: icon missing

Tags: pgadmin, nwjs

The icon on the pgAdmin4 window has gone missing. Is there a way I can restore it?

[image]

I've checked `pgAdmin 4\v7\runtime\package.json` which lists `"icons": { "256": "assets/pgAdmin4.png" },` but I'm not sure Windows' icon is derived from that. And I can't seem to find any `*.ico` in the `pgAdmin 4` folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to the known issue with NW.js. Until it's fixed, pgAdmin can move back to 0.72.0.

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/8039

Comment: Good to know, I'll patiently await a new version from nwjs that fixes this, then...